# Would this question be a good fit for this site?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

As one of the moderators of the [Software Recommendations SE site](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com), I received an urgent request to migrate a question to Graphic Design SE:

https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2953/please-immediately-migrate-this-question-to-graphic-design-se

After reading through much of the help documents on Graphics Design SE, I tend to think the referenced question likely would not be a good fit for Graphics Design SE, but maybe (and hopefully for the OP) it could work here.

To me, the best place for that question is where it is, Software Recommendations SE.  But if this community thinks it would be appropriate for the OP to ask here, I'm sure the OP will appreciate it.

I figure the best thing to do to be kind and helpful is to simply ask: Would that question be on-topic on this SE site, and possibly receive a good answer?

As a side-note, we don't have a direct migration path from SR SE to GD SE, so any such migration would have to be performed manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, the part about how to do this would probably fit quite well. Besides the answer it got pretty much covers it. Its very much the exact same answer they would get on graphic design.

But to be honest OP will also get a another answer and that is to rewrite it with a pen. Because that is a perfectly valid answer.

Theres never enough migration paths on the network.

Comment: Thank you for all your feedback.  Much appreciated.